# Check if player has an item in Minecraft and if so remove it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a server where a certain item is banned. How do I get to know if a player has it in their inventory, and, if so, how can I delete all instances of it using command blocks?

Comment: I'm pretty this has been asked many times before but I can't find a post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`clear`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/clear) command.

Example:

`/clear @a minecraft:flint_and_steel`

`@a` is a [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors) which selects all players. You can supply any item ID instead of `minecraft:flint_and_steel`. The Minecraft wiki should tell you the ID of any item on it's page. For example, see the [Sword](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sword?so=search#ID) page for all the different sword IDs.

Because you need this to execute every tick, make sure this Command Block is set to "repeating" mode. Otherwise, it will only clear the items once.

Answer (score 0):

No need to detect; if an item is outright banned from the server, you just need to run the clear command on a command block in repeating mode. The command is `/clear @a [item]`.

Comment: This adds not very much to the previous answer.

Comment: @pinckerman It doesn't have to. Just because an answer is there doesn't mean I can't post another one.

Comment: You are encouraged to post new answers if they add something new, or if they reorganize information into a more readable format. You are essentially saying the same things already written. So what's the point?

Comment: @pinckerman This is in a more readable format, as it is a simplified version.